# Single sign on is not working in .net, different auth cookie length

Tags: asp.net, .net, authentication, iis, single-sign-on

I have two subdomains, say

```
abc.domain.com // main application used for signing in
xyz.domain.com
```

I'm trying to implement Single sign on, but it's not working for me. I've set up web.config accordingly for `abc.domain.com`:

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
       <forms name="my_name" 
       defaultUrl="/" 
       loginUrl="/login" 
       protection="All" path="/" 
       domain="domain.com" 
       cookieless="UseCookies" 
       timeout="10080" 
       slidingExpiration="false" />
    </authentication>
```

And for `xyz.domain.com` :

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms name="my_name"
   defaultUrl="http://abc.domain.com/"     
   loginUrl="http://abc.domain.com/login" 
   protection="All"  
   path="/"
   domain="domain.com" 
   cookieless="UseCookies"  
   timeout="10080" 
   slidingExpiration="false" />
</authentication>
```

I have the same machine key for both:

```
<machineKey validationKey="122...3E9" decryptionKey="AC1...007" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

Both application built with the same target framework (4.5) and run by the same application pool. (I tried different pools too)

I don't create auth ticket myself, just use standard

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Email, model.RememberMe);
```

I've seen a few similar questions, but nothing helped me. I've noticed that if I set the auth cookie in `xyz` the cookie value has different length, I think it is related to the problem, but can't figure out why this happens.

Can anyone advise on it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using same attribute values for `<form>` element in both the environments. machine Key should be the same too